# Расстояние между 2 точками координаты

Tags: java, математика, методы, формулы

Я хочу найти расстояние между точкой x и точкой y. В методе getDistance сама формула (взял ее за основу, так как на всех форумах ее предлагают, так как в математике я не силен). Вот только возвращает по итогу постоянно 0. Я точно сверил формулу и она должна вроде как работать, но не хочет.

```
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getDistance(Point point) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - point.x, 2) + Math.pow(y - point.y, 2));
    }
}
```

Вот код, который я использую для проверки.

```
public class PointDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point point = new Point(10, 5);
        System.out.printf("X %f\nY %f\n", point.getX(), point.getY());
        System.out.printf("distance %f\n", point.getDistance(point));
        point.setX(1);
        point.setY(41);
        System.out.printf("X %f\nY %f\n", point.getX(), point.getY());
        System.out.printf("distance %f\n", point.getDistance(point));
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы измеряете расстояние между одинаковыми точками. Расстояние - ноль, как и должно быть.

Comment: `point.getDistance(point)` - расстояние откуда докуда?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можно подробней ? Я очень слаб в математике. Хочу понять

Comment: @Igor по идее от x до y. Но это по идее. По итогу идея не работает. И вот хочу понять почему

Comment: @Tokamo `x` и `y` - это числа. Вы говорите о расстоянии между точками на плоскости. Положение *каждой* точки на плоскости задается двумя числами - ее координатами `x` и `y`. Вы себе представляете кооpдинатную плоскость? Если нет, то Вам не следует решать такие задачи.

Comment: @Tokamo, математика у вас верная. Создайте две разные точки, дайте им разные координаты, вычислите расстояние и вы увидите, что оно больше нуля.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy получается, создать x1, x2 и y1, y2 ? Где x1 и y1, и x2 и y2 координаты одной точки ?

Comment: @Igor я понял. По факту, это 2D, где координата описывается двумя значениями. X и Y. И для каждой точки мне необходим X и Y. Вот сейчас я понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь. Благодаря вам я допер в чем суть. Я задавал лишь одну точку, а надо было две. Метод расчета я не менял. Менял входные данные. Создал вторую координату point2 и далее через метод уже проводил правильные расчеты.

```
Point point1 = new Point(10, 5);
Point point2 = new Point(12, 30);
System.out.printf("Start value:\nX1 = %f\nY1 = %f\n", point1.getX(), point1.getY());
System.out.printf("X2 = %f\nY2 = %f\n", point2.getX(), point2.getY());
System.out.printf("distance = %f\n", point1.getDistance(point2));
```